# Why do I get different results depending on how many child processes I use?

Tags: c, file, operating-system, pipe, fork

I am working on a simple C program that recursively creates children and uses them to sum all the numbers in a file, depending on user input. There are three predetermined file sizes that the user can chose from, as well as three set amounts of children that can be generated. In theory, there could be any number of children or any size file, but for the sake of simplicity there are only 3 here.

The problem I'm running into is, no matter which file I use, the only time the sum is correct is when the program uses only 1 child. With other amounts of children, such as 4, the number is close, but not quite right. Can someone offer me any insight as to what is causing this issue?

Here is the section of code I think is problematic:

```
// C program to demonstrate use of fork() with pipe()
// By: Maxwell Wendlandt
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *file;
    int numForks;
    // initialize pipes for up to 4 children
    int fd[4][2];
    // initialize up to 4 processes 
    pid_t pid[4];
    int total = 0;
    int finalResult = 0;
    char fileName[10] = "";
    int fileNum;
    int numLines;

    // ask which file to scan
    printf("Enter file number 1 (1000 nums), 2 (10000 nums) or 3 (100000 nums):\n");
    scanf("%i", &fileNum);
    // chose the file
    switch(fileNum)
    {
    case 1 :
        printf("File 1 selected.\n");
        strcpy(fileName, "file1.dat");
        numLines = 1000;
        break;
    case 2 :
        printf("File 2 selected.\n");
        strcpy(fileName, "file2.dat");
        numLines = 10000;
        break;
    case 3 :
        printf("File 3 selected.\n");
        strcpy(fileName, "file3.dat");
        numLines = 100000;
        break;
    default :
        printf("Enter a valid file number next time.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    // ask how many children (forks)
    printf("Do you want 1, 2 or 4 child processes?\n");
    scanf("%i", &numForks);

    for (int i = 0; i < numForks + 1; i++)
    {
        if (pipe(fd[i]) == -1)
        {
            printf("Error with creating pipe.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < numForks; i++)
    {
        pid[i] = fork();
        if(pid[i] == -1)
        {
            printf("Error creating child.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if(pid[i] == 0)
        {
            // children
            int sum = 0, num = 0;
            int start, end;
            file = fopen(fileName, "r");
            
            start = i * (numLines / numForks);
            printf("start: %i\n", start);
            end = ((i + 1) * (numLines / numForks));
            printf("end: %i\n", end);
            fseek(file, (start * 4), SEEK_SET);

            for(int i = start; i < end; i++)
            {
                fscanf(file, "%d", &num);
                printf("num on line %d is: %d\n", i + 1, num);
                sum += num;
            }

            printf("sum in child: %d\n", sum);
        
            write(fd[i][1], &sum, sizeof(sum));
            close(fd[i][1]);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    // parent
    for(int i = 0; i < numForks; i++)
    {
        read(fd[i][0], &total, sizeof(total));
        close(fd[i][0]);
        finalResult += total; 
    }
    
    printf("The grand total: %i\n", finalResult);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < numForks; i++)
    {
        wait(NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Values being *"... close, not quite right."* and only correct when some constant is `1` points towards rounding errors introduced by integer division.

Comment: The other concern is that `fseek` deals in precise terms of raw bytes, but `fscanf` reads arbitrary amounts of *formatted* data to yield a result. Do your numbers contain fixed padding? Is that how `start * 3` makes sense - two digits and the newline per number?

Comment: There is *a lot* of information missing from this example that could be problematic. Please post a complete [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), with a `main` and `#include` directives. Please provide an example of the file being read, and the expected output for a given set of inputs.

Comment: @Oka So to add some clarity, the file options are 1000 ints, 10000 ints, or 100000 ints each. The numbers are all 3 digit numbers (thus why I multiply start * 3 to account for fseek only counting bytes). Additionally, the fork options are 1 fork, 2 forks, and 4 forks. With those numbers, and the only division in the code being numLines (total numbers in the file) / numForks (1, 2, or 4 children), wouldn't rounding errors not be possible? Also, I updated the code with all information that should be needed.

Comment: How is the text in the file formatted? What delineates the numbers? `fseek` needs to account for those bytes as well.

Comment: Note: the children are always reading from the first file (`if(pid[i] == 0) { /* ... */ strcpy(fileName, "file1.dat");`).

Comment: @Oka each line of the file has one 3 digit number on it. So a 1000 number file has 1000 lines.

Comment: Thank you for the note about the file1 always being read. That was from some earlier testing and I forgot to remove it. I had been testing the program using only file one anyway, so even though I fixed it, the main issue still persists.

Comment: Are the numbers padded with zeroes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> each line of the file has one 3 digit number on it. So a 1000 number file has 1000 lines.

This means each line consists of <strike>four</strike> five bytes - the three digits, the carriage return, and the newline character. e.g., `123\r\n`. The off-by-two error here

```
fseek(file, (start * 3), SEEK_SET);
```

will cause each seek to drift, and each child will read from an earlier position than they should. If each line is five bytes, this should be `start * 5`.

---

Aside: I would hazard a guess the numbers in your files are padded with zeroes (see the generation example below).

If so, the [`fscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) specifier `%i` may not be desirable, as it acts as `strtol` with a base of `0`, meaning the numbers base is determined by its first characters.

This may lead to confusing results when zero padded numbers are parsed as octal. For example:

- `004` - octal, value `4`.
- `040` - octal, value `32`.
- `400` - decimal, value `400`.
- `009` - octal, invalid value (`0`).
- `011` - octal, value `9`.

`%d` will parse the inputs as base-10 numbers.

---

This has a few problems.

```
printf("Do you want 1, 2 or 4 child processes?\n");
scanf("%i", &numForks);
for (int i = 0; i < numForks + 1; i++) {
    if (pipe(fd[i]) == -1)
    /* ... */
```

`i < numForks + 1` is an off-by-one error. The user can also enter an arbitrary number.This will invoke [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) if `fd` is accessed via an out-of-bounds index.

In general, you should be checking the return values of more functions, such as `scanf`, `fscanf`, `fseek`, `write`, and `read`, to ensure you are working with valid data.

Prefer `perror` and `fprintf(stderr, ...)` to print useful error messages to the correct stream.

---

A very cursory refactoring:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wait.h>

int main(void)
{
    int numForks;
    // initialize pipes for up to 4 children
    int fd[4][2];
    // initialize up to 4 processes
    pid_t pid[4];

    int total = 0;
    int finalResult = 0;
    char fileName[10] = "";
    int fileNum;
    int numLines;

    printf("Enter file number 1 (1000 nums), 2 (10000 nums) or 3 (100000 nums):\n");
    if (1 != scanf("%d", &fileNum)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid number of files.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    switch (fileNum) {
        case 1:
            printf("File 1 selected.\n");
            strcpy(fileName, "file1.dat");
            numLines = 1000;
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("File 2 selected.\n");
            strcpy(fileName, "file2.dat");
            numLines = 10000;
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("File 3 selected.\n");
            strcpy(fileName, "file3.dat");
            numLines = 100000;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Enter a valid file number next time.\n");
            return 0;
    }

    printf("Do you want 1, 2 or 4 child processes?\n");
    if (1 != scanf("%d", &numForks) || 1 > numForks || numForks > 4 || numForks == 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid number of child processes.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numForks; i++) {
        if (pipe(fd[i]) == -1) {
            perror("pipe");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numForks; i++) {
        pid[i] = fork();

        if (pid[i] == -1) {
            perror("fork");
            return 1;
        }

        // children
        if (pid[i] == 0) {
            int sum = 0, num = 0;
            int start, end;
            FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");

            if (!file) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Child %d failed to open ", i + 1);
                perror(fileName);
                return 1;
            }

            start = i * (numLines / numForks);
            end = ((i + 1) * (numLines / numForks));
            printf("start: %d\nend: %d\n", start, end);

            if (-1 == fseek(file, (start * 4), SEEK_SET)) {
                perror("fseek");
                return 1;
            }

            for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
                if (1 == fscanf(file, "%d", &num))
                    sum += num;

            printf("sum in child: %d\n", sum);

            write(fd[i][1], &sum, sizeof sum);
            close(fd[i][1]);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // parent
    for (int i = 0; i < numForks; i++) {
        if (sizeof total == read(fd[i][0], &total, sizeof total))
            finalResult += total;
        close(fd[i][0]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numForks; i++)
        wait(NULL);

    printf("The grand total: %d\n", finalResult);
}
```

The code used to generate files to test with (`./gen 1000 > file1.dat`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i = 0;

    if (argc > 1)
        i = atoi(argv[1]);

    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

    while (i-- > 0)
        printf("%03d\n", rand() % 1000);
}
```

And a sanity checker (`./sanity-check < file1.dat`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int sum = 0, num;

    while (1 == scanf("%d", &num))
        sum += num;

    printf("%d\n", sum);
}
```

Comment: So even after making all the suggested changes, my code still has the exact same issue. I even ran the updated version of my problem that you so kindly provided. Same result. It might be useful information that the files I use are special because they never have leading 0's, but otherwise look exactly like you imagined them too. I updated the code in my original post with my corrections, in case you still see issues or things I missed. Please note that for the sake of not letting the code get too long, I did not implement the data validation yet. Thanks.

Comment: Forget that, I solved it, thanks to your answer. It was not an off by one error, but off by 2! I needed to do start * 5, to account for \r\n. Thanks! Funny this took my so much effort when the issue was literally 1 number... But I guess thats programming for you! Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, good to hear. I've updated my answer to reflect the new information, so it's not as confused. Consider marking this as [resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (or possibly delete the question, since its a touch muddled in scope. I'll let you decide if its useful to others, though).